# Multiple cascade paths warning and not sure why. The alternative if I can't?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I originally had the following two tables.

**tbl_Vehicle**

- VehicleID int identity

**tbl_VehicleAssignment**

- RecordID int identity
- VehicleID int FK
- EmployeeID int
- Original bit

When a vehicle comes in, it has an originally assignee, noted by the [Original] column in the second table above. Also set ON DELETE CASCADE, so if a vehicle is deleted, so are any associated assignment records. No problem there.

I decided this wasn't the best way to organize the data, and adding rules on the VehicleAssignment table to enforce only one vehicle can have a single 1 for Original seemed expensive in the long run. When I say that, I have several tables like this, some of which will grow quite large, so thinking of performance.

I then decided to change my tables like so:

**tbl_Vehicle**

- VehicleID int identity
- Orig_Assignment int NULL

**tbl_VehicleAssignment**

- RecordID int identity
- VehicleID int FK
- EmployeeID int

The problem is, I then wanted to add a constraint so that if RecordID in tbl_VehicleAssignment was deleted, it set Orig_Assignment back to NULL.

Getting the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Orig_Vehicle_VehicleAssignment'
>   on table 'tbl_Vehicle' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

But I'm not sure why exactly. If a vehicle is deleted, it cascades and deletes assignment records. But I'd also like to set [Orig_Assignment] to NULL when its associated record is deleted. I don't see how the two cross paths to cause multiple cascade paths. What's interesting though, is if I use the table designer wizard to create this, it actually saves the constraint in the **tbl_VehicleAssignment** table, but fails on the **tbl_Vehicle** table, and although closing the dialog and looking at the relationships in the tables look correct, there's obviously something wrong.

If I can't get around this, what would be the best method?

**1. Trigger**
I'd rather stay away from this

**2. Another table for originals that allows nulls**

So it would be like:

**tbl_VehicleOriginal**

- VehicleID int
- Orig_Assignment int NULL
- Orig_SomethingElse int NULL
- Orig_Etc. int NULL

This would create a row for every row in the tbl_Vehicle table.

**3. Another table for originals but only when present**

Such as:

tbl_VehicleOriginal

- VehicleID int PK
- RecordType PK
- RecordID FK

*I suppose my question is, why can't I just add the constraint? If it's not possible, what's the best way to organize the data?*

**UPDATE - Scripts to build the example**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A_Vehicle](
    [VehicleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Orig_Assignment] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A_Vehicle] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VehicleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A_VehicleAssignment](
    [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VehicleID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A_VehicleAssignment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A_VehicleAssignment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_A_VehicleAssignment_A_Vehicle] FOREIGN KEY([VehicleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[A_Vehicle] ([VehicleID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A_VehicleAssignment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_A_VehicleAssignment_A_Vehicle]
GO

-- The below will fail
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A_Vehicle]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Orig_A_VehicleAssignment_A_Vehicle] FOREIGN KEY([Orig_Assignment])
REFERENCES [dbo].[A_VehicleAssignment] ([RecordID])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
```

Comment: are you sure you accidentally not included Orig_Assignment in your FK?

Comment: I'm sure I'm selecting the correct columns and tables.

Comment: pls add the code you wrote to set it NULL; it would also help if you can include script for your foreign key code

Comment: Can you the ddl for the tables and the constraints you are trying?

Comment: Sure @SeanLange ... I'll create some test tables, as my actual tables are more detailed than the examples. brb in a moment :)

Comment: That will be a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanLange Please see my editing question. Thank you

Comment: That helps considerably to visualize what you are trying to do. The reason this can't be done is because you could potentially have an endless loop here. You have a vehicle and when it is deleted you cascade and delete the assignment. But when an assignment is deleted it potentially goes back to a row that has already been deleted. See the logical issue here?

Comment: @SeanLange Well crap... yes, now I see the issue. What would you suggest? I'm a big fan of setting rules to protect integrity, and not relying even on SPs or the application.

Comment: IMHO, I avoid cascading deletes. I can do enough damage on my own without the database helping. OTOH, stored procedures allow for explicitly stating the logic needed to perform complex operations and allow them to be contained within a suitable transaction. SPs also allow you to separate access to the tables from access to the functionality, e.g. allow users to read the tables, but force deletes to go through your SPs.

Comment: That is a tough call for sure. Not using cascading means you have the potential of bad data if somebody deletes data without using the prescribed procedure. It is a double edged sword for sure. I use cascading deletes but very sparingly. I have probably used fewer than 10 in my career.

Comment: I use cascade often and have never had an issue, although I always use transactions in SPs with rollback, and always test in a staging environment. As long as the direction is simple, unlike my obvious question that I posted today, it has always served me well. I used to type out the deletes manually. I may have to handle my logic in a SP for my question it seems. I dislike triggers.